# Generic Makefile for PETSc

Tags: c++, makefile, header-files, petsc

I am using a general makefile as follows:

```
# Determine the platform
UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)

# CC
CC := g++

# Folders
SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := build
TARGETDIR := bin

# Targets
EXECUTABLE := NSDG
TARGET := $(TARGETDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)

# Final Paths
INSTALLBINDIR := /usr/local/bin

# Code Lists
SRCEXT := cpp
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))

# Folder Lists
# Note: Intentionally excludes the root of the include folder so the lists are clean
INCDIRS := $(shell find includes/**/* -name '*.h' -exec dirname {} \; | sort | uniq)
INCLIST := $(patsubst includes/%,-I include/%,$(INCDIRS))
BUILDLIST := $(patsubst includes/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(INCDIRS))

# Shared Compiler Flags
CFLAGS := -c
INC := -I include $(INCLIST) -I /usr/local/include
LIB := -L /usr/local/lib -lblas -llapacke -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm

# Platform Specific Compiler Flags
CFLAGS += -std=c++11

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @mkdir -p $(TARGETDIR)
    @echo "Linking..."
    @echo "  Linking $(TARGET)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDLIST)
    @echo "Compiling $<..."; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning $(TARGET)..."; $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)

install:
    @echo "Installing $(EXECUTABLE)..."; cp $(TARGET) $(INSTALLBINDIR)

distclean:
    @echo "Removing $(EXECUTABLE)"; rm $(INSTALLBINDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)

.PHONY: clean
```

The directory structure is as follows all the *.cpp files are contained in the directory src/ and the corresponding header(*.h) files are present in directory includes/. Now I want to add PETSc libraries to it. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you know how you would do it on the command line, without Make? That is, is this a PETSc question, or a Make question?

Comment: I figured it out. Check the answer. BTW it required an equal knowledge of both PETSc as well as makefiles. Sadly, took me around half a day to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. If someone gets stuck in the future I am posting the generic Makefile for a project involving PETSc.

```
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/variables
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/rules

# Determine the platform
UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)

# CC
CC := ${PETSC_DIR}/${PETSC_ARCH}/bin/mpicxx -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fvisibility=hidden -g3 -std=c++11

# Folders
SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := build
TARGETDIR := bin

# Targets
EXECUTABLE := dg_petsc
TARGET := $(TARGETDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)

# Final Paths
INSTALLBINDIR := /usr/local/bin

# Code Lists
SRCEXT := cpp
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))

# Folder Lists
# Note: Intentionally excludes the root of the include folder so the lists are clean
INCDIRS := $(shell find includes/**/* -name '*.h' -exec dirname {} \; | sort | uniq)
INCLIST := $(patsubst includes/%,-I include/%,$(INCDIRS))
BUILDLIST := $(patsubst includes/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(INCDIRS))

# Shared Compiler Flags
CFLAGS := -c
INC := -I include $(INCLIST) -I /usr/local/include -I ${PETSC_DIR}/include -I ${PETSC_DIR}/${PETSC_ARCH}/include
LIB := -L /usr/local/lib ${PETSC_SYS_LIB}

# Platform Specific Compiler Flags
CFLAGS += -std=c++11

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @mkdir -p $(TARGETDIR)
    @echo "Linking..."
    @echo "  Linking $(TARGET)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDLIST)
    @echo "Compiling $<..."; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

clean_project:
    @echo "Cleaning $(TARGET)..."; $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)

install:
    @echo "Installing $(EXECUTABLE)..."; cp $(TARGET) $(INSTALLBINDIR)

distclean:
    @echo "Removing $(EXECUTABLE)"; rm $(INSTALLBINDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)

.PHONY: clean
```